# How to debug performance of salt-ssh

Tags: performance, ssh, salt-stack

I am not happy with the performance of salt-ssh in my context.

It takes up to 30 secs for very small changes with only some requisites.

I want to find the bottleneck.

AFAIK these steps happen if I call `salt-ssh`:

1. ssh connection to root@minion
2. `thin.tgz` get transferred
3. Tree of requisites gets parsed
4. Tree gets applied
5. Result gets returned from the minion.
6. Result gets received on the localhost

I guess this not 100% correct, please leave comments if these steps need an update.

I would like to know how long does `salt-ssh` need to perform each steps.

Does someone know how to debug this?

```
salt:/srv # salt --versions-report
Salt Version:
           Salt: 2016.3.1

Dependency Versions:
           cffi: 0.8.6
       cherrypy: Not Installed
       dateutil: 2.1
          gitdb: 0.5.4
      gitpython: 0.3.2 RC1
          ioflo: Not Installed
         Jinja2: 2.8
        libgit2: 0.21.0
        libnacl: Not Installed
       M2Crypto: 0.22
           Mako: Not Installed
   msgpack-pure: Not Installed
 msgpack-python: 0.4.7
   mysql-python: Not Installed
      pycparser: 2.10
       pycrypto: 2.6.1
         pygit2: 0.21.2
         Python: 2.7.3 (default, Apr 14 2012, 08:58:41) [GCC]
   python-gnupg: Not Installed
         PyYAML: 3.11
          PyZMQ: 15.2.0
           RAET: Not Installed
          smmap: 0.8.2
        timelib: Not Installed
        Tornado: 4.3
            ZMQ: 4.1.2

System Versions:
           dist: SuSE 12.3 x86_64
        machine: x86_64
        release: 3.7.10-1.40-desktop
         system: Linux
        version: openSUSE  12.3 x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `-l debug` to your `salt-ssh` command should give you a lot of information that might help you determine what's taking so long for you.

Also, what's the output of  `salt-ssh --versions-report`?

Comment: `-l debug` prints a lot of messages. I could match some of these lines to me high level steps from the question. Up to now I see no timestamps in the logs. Is there a way to format the logging to contain a timestamp? ... and I added the versions-report to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to see per-state timing data, you can enable state_output_profile in config/master.

```
# On some minions, we get weird output from state.apply
# salt issue #35989 workaround - temporary until 2016.11.0 release
# https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/35989#issuecomment-250611386
# state_output_profile: 'True|False'
```